# how to trigger an event of navigationitem rightBarButtonItem programmatically?

Tags: iphone, rightbarbuttonitem, navigationitem

i created an navigationitem rightBarButtonItem in the following code and I would like to trigger its event programmatically ( just like click the bar button ). search everywhere but can't find how to do it. does anyone know the method? thx a lot.

```
    UIBarButtonItem *reloadbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(Action1:)];
 self.navigationitem.rightBarButtonItem = reloadbutton;
 [reloadbutton release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an action method that you're using with the button, you can just call the method yourself; for example,

```
 [self Action1:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem];
```